# True/False: Let $f:G\to L$ be a homomorphism. If $H \unlhd G$ and $N=\ker(f)\subseteq H$ then $\frac{G}{H}\simeq\frac{G}{N}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f:G\rightarrow L$ be a homomorphism. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N=\ker(f)\subseteq H$ then $\frac{G}{H}\simeq \frac{G}{N}$.

Is this statement true?

*From the comments . . .*

I'm trying to prove that $G/H\simeq f(G)/f(H)$ (in the conditions above) and basically I arrived at a point where I need to show that the statemet above is true. Maybe I made some mistake somewhere . . .

Comment: No, this is not so.

Comment: Why would you think this?  Suppose $L=G$ and $f$ is the identity map.  Then $\ker (f)=(e)$ so $G/N=G$  But $G$ could have other normal subgroups...

Comment: I'm trying to prove that $\frac{G}{H}\simeq \frac{f(G)}{f(H)}$ (in the conditions above) and basically I arrived at a point where I need to show that the statemet above is true. Maybe I made some mistake somewhere...

Comment: I don't think there's any hope of general conditions making something like that true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers on the motivating problem (the problem that the OP arrived at is not true, as the comments state).

Suppose that $\ker(f)=N$, $N\subseteq H$, and $H\triangleleft G$.  We want to show that 
$$
\frac{G}{H}\simeq\frac{f(G)}{f(H)}.
$$
Note first that $f(H)\triangleleft f(G)$.  In particular, suppose that $f(g)\in f(G)$ and $f(h)\in f(H)$.  Then, $f(g)f(h)f(g)^{-1}=f(ghg^{-1})$, and, since $H$ is normal in $G$, $ghg^{-1}=h'\in H$.  Therefore, $f(ghg^{-1})=f(h')\in f(H)$.  Therefore, $f(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $f(G)$.

As is typically the case in this type of problem, we define a map.  Our map will be
$$
\varphi:\frac{G}{H}\rightarrow\frac{f(G)}{f(H)}
$$
defined as
$$
\varphi(gH)=f(g)f(H).
$$
We must check that this map is a well-defined homomorphism which is injective and surjective.

We begin by checking that this map is well-defined.  Suppose that $g_1H=g_2H$.  In this case, we know that $g_2^{-1}g_1=h\in H$.  On the other hand, 
$$
\varphi(g_1H)=f(g_1)f(H)=f(g_2h)f(H)=f(g_2)f(h)f(H)=f(g_2)f(H)=\varphi(g_2H).
$$

Surjectivity is straight-forward since an element of $\frac{f(G)}{f(H)}$ is of the form $f(g_1)f(H)$.  This is the image of $\varphi(g_1H)$.

Injectivity is slightly more tricky.  Suppose that $\varphi(g_1H)=\varphi(g_2H)$.  Then $f(g_1)f(H)=f(g_2)f(H)$, so $f(g_2)^{-1}f(g_1)=f(g_2^{-1}g_1)\in f(H)$.  Hence, there is some $h$ such that $f(g_2^{-1}g_1)=f(h)$.  In other words, $g_2^{-1}g_1h^{-1}\in K$.  Since $K\subseteq H$, $g_2^{-1}g_1h^{-1}\in H$, and so $g_2^{-1}g_1\in H$, and hence $g_1H=g_2H$.

Finally, we check that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.  We observe that 
$$
\varphi((g_1H)(g_2H))=\varphi(g_1g_2H)=f(g_1g_2)f(H)
$$
and
$$
\varphi(g_1H)\varphi(g_2H)=f(g_1)f(H)f(g_2)f(H)=f(g_1)f(g_2)f(H)=f(g_1g_2)f(H).
$$